# Performance of Linq query is very slow

Tags: c#, linq

I have 700 records that have different columns with type string and I want to select all records using this code:

```cs
public virtual object GetAll()
{
    var AllList = unitOfWork.Repository<STUser>().GetAll().ToList();

    return (from STUser in AllList
            select new
            {
                STUser.ID,
                FullName = STUser.HRPerson.LastName,
                STUser.USR,
                STUser.Active,
                STUser.TryCount,
                STUser.Description           
            }).OrderByDescending(i => i.ID).ToList();
}
```

However, unitl Fill "var AllList" is good but when Linq query execution is very slow.
I removed `FullName = STUser.HRPerson.LastName,` line and it was executed very fast.
`Join` clause slowed it down.

I ran SQL profiler for every row in the List and it looks like it executes the Query 700 times.
Query is

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Extent1].[EnFullName] AS [EnFullName], 
[Extent1].[FatherName] AS [FatherName], 
[Extent1].[GenderID] AS [GenderID], 
[Extent1].[NationalCode] AS [NationalCode], 
[Extent1].[IdentityNumber] AS [IdentityNumber], 
[Extent1].[BirthCityID] AS [BirthCityID], 
[Extent1].[BirthDate] AS [BirthDate], 
[Extent1].[VeteranID] AS [VeteranID], 
[Extent1].[PersonPic] AS [PersonPic], 
[Extent1].[Active] AS [Active], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[DateTimes] AS [DateTimes]
FROM [dbo].[HRPerson] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=1502
```

Please help me.

Comment: That's the effect of Lazy Loading and you probably want Eager - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

Comment: @HansKeﬆing **when** the query is executed does not at all influence the **duration** of the query. However performing the same query again and again is another issue and **does** effect performance.

Comment: What about not using the `.ToList()` on the `var AllList = unitOfWork.Repository<STUser>().GetAll().ToList();`

Comment: did you profile this, e.g. using DotTrace? where exactly are your performance-bottlenecks? Chances are you´re looking at the whrong code here. From what you´ve posted there´s not much for us to do here.

Comment: @HimBromBeere the call to `STUser.HRPerson.LastName` will probably cause the db to be queried for every STUser, especially after the `.GetAll().ToList()`. An eager load would have gotten that data in the first GetAll query, a lazy load will execute extra queries on access - thus causing "700 executes" and a slowdown

Comment: `OrderByDescending()` the first query and avoid to assign `STUser.HRPerson.LastName` like that. If you can change the source class to produce that value, better. You can generate the same results with a single query. `ToList()` only if it's actually necessary to materialize these objects right away. Returning an `Object` may not be a good idea.

Comment: use take and skip in linq query. You search it on google and you can easily understand.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing i disable LAzyloading with this this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; but not any ralation load

Comment: @Jimi i remove OrderByDescending() but this not effected

Comment: What query is executed 700 times? Getting an STUser, or getting the HRPerson.LastName for each user?

Comment: Try changing that `.GetAll().ToList()` to `.GetAll().Include(u => u.HRPerson).ToList()`, to try and eagerly get that hrperson while you are getting all users, instead of as separate queries (as I assume is happening)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing relation query

Comment: @HansKeﬆing i use IEnumerable<T> in GetAll() and not accept .Include(u => u.HRPerson).ToList()

Comment: @HansKeﬆing are you remote to me and see my code?

Comment: I was hoping your repo GetAll returned an IQueryable. Pity. You will have to find a way to get that HRPerson along with the STUsers

Comment: @HansKeﬆing i changed my repo to returned IQueryable but not affected. yes  iam tired to search a soulotion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211718/discussion-between-xxxsenatorxxx-and-hans-keing).

Answer (score 1):

i use IQueryable in repo and add Include(u => u.HRPerson) its ok

```
var AllList = unitOfWork.Repository<STUser>().GetAll().Include(u => u.HRPerson).ToList();
```

thankyou @HansKeﬆing for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought I would like to share: (I'm not familiar with that platform)

What about this:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<YourDataObject> GetAll()
{
    var result = from STUser in unitOfWork.Repository<STUser>().GetAll() // << what is GetAll()??
                 orderby STUser.ID
                 select new YourDataObject // <-- you should create a data holder class for it
                 {
                    STUser.ID,
                    FullName = STUser.HRPerson.LastName,
                    STUser.USR,
                    STUser.Active,
                    STUser.TryCount,
                    STUser.Description
                 });

    return result;
}
```

By doing the ordering before the creation of the data holder class, you **might** use an optimalization on the database side.

Comment: GetAll() is method that call  IEnumerable<T> models = dbSetGlobalERP.ToList();

iuse your code but not affected. help me my problem very big. van you remote to me and see my code?

Comment: What you seek is, `IQueryable<>` so the ordering can be done serverside. What does `unitOfWork.Repository<STUser>()` returns?

Comment: i use IQueryable<> but not affected. return { ID = 960, FullName = " john smith- 2294089499", USR = "h.ranjbar", Active = true, TryCount = 0, Description = "", DateTimes = "1398/10/28 15:12" }

Comment: Able to try Jeroen's snippet code, but without ".GetAll()" ? Since the unitOfWork.Repository<STUser>() returns IQueryable, and we do not want to evaluate it with .GetAll() yet.

Comment: @Markuzy i test it but not affected

Answer (score 0):

You could try using .AsNoTracking() on your query.

From the Microsoft docs -

> No tracking queries are useful when the results are used in a read-only scenario. They're quicker to execute because there's no need to set up the change tracking information. If you don't need to update the entities retrieved from the database, then a no-tracking query should be used. You can swap an individual query to be no-tracking.

More here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking

Comment: i use AsNoTracking() but this not effected